# Is there a way to transform a table this way in R?

Tags: r, transform

Please help, I want to transform a table in R this way bellow, from this:

| ID | Product 1 | Product 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 | 30 |
| 3 | 50 | 0 |

To this:

| ID | Product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 1 | 50 |

I am finding it difficult, hope you can help me with this

Comment: Please give us some context so that we are not guessing at what you are trying to do. I, for one, see no clear relationship between the numbers in the tables you show for before and after the transform. Consider reading about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_longer()`!

```
library(tidyverse)
#first, make the data
df <- tibble(ID          = c(1,2,3),
             `Product 1` = c(0, 20, 50),
             `Product 2` = c(10, 30 , 0)
)
#then transform it
df_trans <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = !ID,              #all columns except the ID column
               names_to = "Product",
               names_prefix = "Product" #removes the "Product" prefix
               values_to = "Amount"
  ) %>%
  filter(Amount > 0) #you don't want 0s, from your sample?
```